# iTextSharp CSS sheet not linking

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, itext

Hello I have an MVC application where a page is converted into a PDF using iTextSharp. I have a separate PDF style sheet called pdfStyleSheet.css that links to _PDFLayout. When linking the CSS page to my page layout the styles aren't being passed. My link is below. However if I put an inner style in _PDFLayout it works fine. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

The code below does not work

**_PDFLayout** Link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Content/pdfStyleSheet.css" />
```

**pdfStyleSheet.css**

```
.test {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Requestor)
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult getPDF(int id)
{
    MEOmodel model = _repository.GetMEOById(id);
    return new PdfActionResult(model);
}
```

Comment: iTextSharp doesn't know what ASP.Net or MVC is nor does it know what `~` means. In your parsing code you're going to need to find a way to resolve that to an absolute URL, either HTTP based or file-based. If you post your processing code we can probably show you what needs to be updated.

Comment: Makes sense, I added my controller code to the question. Any questions let me know

Comment: This is the example I have been going off of https://github.com/andyhutch77/mvcrazortopdf